# Angular 1.6 - Controller registred but still not detected

Tags: angularjs, debugging

I am working with "Angular 1.6.5", I registered a controller but the console still showing the same error:

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'CardholderAboutYouController' is not registered.

Here's my code:

```
angular.module('app.core')
.controller('CardholderAboutYouController', CardholderAboutYouController);

CardholderAboutYouController.$inject = [];
function CardholderAboutYouController(){ }
```

Comment: did you inject the module correctly? `angular.module('app', ['app.core'])`

Comment: are you loading controller js file also while loading index.html

Comment: Yes of corse, `angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'angularMoment',
    'angular-preload-image',
    'truncate',
    'app.routes',
    'app.core']`

Comment: @Kumar, `        .when('/cardholder/aboutyou', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/cardholderAboutYou/cardholderAboutYou.tpl.html',
            controller: 'CardholderAboutYouController as CardholderAboutYou'
        })`

Comment: controllers are working perfectely on other pages, it's only not working on a new fragment i added.

Comment: @Kumar, that was the answer, i thought it was like angular 2+, i forgot that i have to inject files manually. Thank you.